# Google+ integration does not show account picker for devices with single google account

Tags: android, google-play-services

I am trying to implement Google+ integration in one of my android app.But i am not seeing Account picker if there is only one account on my device.

How can i show the account picker in such case?

Comment: I suggest you do not. Asking the user to choose an account when the device has only one account does not make sense and that's why it's made the way it is.

Comment: I agree with your point but there is a case in my app where on clicking of something user need to be signed in and in such cases user doesn't know that he should sign in to access that feature.By looking at account chooser he can decide.

Comment: IMO if the app require sign in when the user initiates certain actions, I really see it much better to show a toast with "Sign in required" message and then the user can choose to sign in from the menu or continue normally. This is better than showing a popup which in this case the account picker and the user refuses by pressing the back button every time.

Answer (score 0):

That's how I show it:

```
  scopes.add(AnalyticsScopes.ANALYTICS_READONLY);

                credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(this, scopes);
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(appPreferences.getUserName()))
                {
                        try
                        {

                                startActivityForResult(credential.newChooseAccountIntent(), REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER);
                        }
                        catch (ActivityNotFoundException e)
                        {

                                Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.gps_missing), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                return;
                        }

                }
```